# A complete url rewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a complete url rewrite code(if thats what you called it) that can change...

```
http://example.com/index.php?i=main&page=5
http://example.com/administrator/page.php?mod=100&access=granted
```

to

```
http://example.com/main/5
http://example.com/administrator/100/granted
```

I have tried using other method that was suggest online, but getting error 500. I don't know what went wrong.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+administrator/page\.php\?mod=([^&]+)&access=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /administrator%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^administrator/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /administrator/page.php?mod=$1&access=$2

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?i=([^&]+)&page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?i=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hmm... doesn't work. It still stays the same url. 

Is there a condition/requirement before applying rewrite url method?